# Vector inequalities with known bounds

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors

Let us assume that we have two vectors $\mathbb{v}$ and $\mathbb{u}$ such that

$\|\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{u}\| \leq A$

and

$\|\mathbb{u}\| \leq B$

where $A > B > 0$

The question is:

is $\|\mathbb{v}\| \leq A - B$ valid?

Comment: Do you know the triangle inequality?

Comment: I do. But I feel I'm missing something.

Comment: I made a silly mistake. One moment and I will fix it.

Comment: Hehe.. thanks for your time :)

Comment: You're very welcome. Answered now. Did you have a way to get to the better bound $A-B$? We can try to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: You helped me make a breakthrough. I'm writing the answer as we speak.

Comment: Oh good! Excited to see.

Comment: Such a graceful Count. Be well my dear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the reverse triangle inequality, we have $\|v\|-\|u\|\leq \|v+u\|\leq A$ and hence $\|v\|\leq A+B$. I'm afraid we can't do better than that with the information given, unless I've made a gross error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not.

Suppose that $\|\mathbb{v}\| \leq A-B$ is true. Then

$\|\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{u} - \mathbb{u}\| \leq A-B$

which, by the reverse triangle inequality becomes

$\bigg| \|\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{u}\| - \|\mathbb{u}\| \bigg| \leq \|(\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{u}) - \mathbb{u}\| \leq A-B$

which means that

$\|\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{u}\| - \|\mathbb{u}\| \leq A -B$

and hence, by the assumption that $\|\mathbb{v} + \mathbb{u}\| \leq A$

$- \|\mathbb{u}\| \leq -B \Leftrightarrow \|\mathbb{u}\| \geq B$

which is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand your first step. You can put $\|v+u\|-\|u\|$, though, and get your result starting in step two.

Comment: Nice job, in any case.

Comment: My Count, this has taken some hours of my day so far, so, as silly as it seems, I would like to make small steps so as to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Well that's a good thing, but my point is that you might have written an untrue statement. But the meat is there, and it is good. If it has taken you that long, then a break is in order. Return here later, and go do something relaxing for a bit. :)

Comment: Hm.. interesting! I will, yes. It's late where I am and I've grown weary. Toodaloo!